# Concise definition of Getter and Setter for nesting properties of an object in ES5 or ES6

Tags: javascript

I need to create getter and setter for nesting object in JavaScript.
At the moment I am using `Object.defineProperty()` in the code below.

Targeting ES5 or ES6.

I would like

- Do you know a less verbose way (or better alternative) to write this?
- Alternative solution to the use of .bind(base) on getter and setter properties.

```js
        var base = {
            _name: 'default',
            _properties: {
                _top: 0
            },
            constructor: function () {
            }
        };

        Object.defineProperty(base, 'name', {
            get: function () {
                return this._name;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this._name = value;
            }
        });
        Object.defineProperty(base, 'properties', {
            get: function () {
                return this._properties;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this._properties = value;
            }
        });
        // nesting properties
        Object.defineProperty(base.properties, 'top', {
            get: function () {
                return this._properties._top;
            }.bind(base),
            set: function (value) {
                this._properties._top = value;
                console.log('WORKS!');
            }.bind(base)
        });

        console.log(base.name);
        base.name = 'Foo';
        console.log(base.name);
        console.log(base.properties.top);
        base.properties.top = 1000;
        console.log(base.properties.top);
```

Comment: @JonSurrell yes ES5 and ES6 is ok, I have edited my question... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the idea? Tested and working es6 via babel on jsbin.

```
var base = {
  _name: 'default',
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  },

  set name(n) {
    return this._name = n;
  },

  _properties: {
    _top: 0,
    get top() {
      return this._top;
    },
    set top(t) {
      return this._top = t;
    },

  },

  get properties() {
    return this._properties;
  },

};
```

Or class based version:

```
class Base {
  constructor() {
    this._name = 'default';
    this._properties = {
      _top: 0,
      get top() { return this._top; },
      set top(val) { return this._top = val; }
    };
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(n) {
    return this._name = n;
  }

  get properties() {
    return this._properties;
  }

}

var b = new Base();
```